# FindElementsByCssSelector method not found on selenium IWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium

```
foreach (IWebElement element in driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("tbody.items tr"))
{
    grid[2,i].Value = element.FindElementsByCssSelector("td.d strong");//error here
    //more attempts to find elements here
}
```

> Error CS1061  'IWebElement' does not contain a definition for
>   'FindElementsByCssSelector' and no extension method
>   'FindElementsByCssSelector' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IWebElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly
>   reference?)

As you can see, I'm trying to find elements, within elements. I am looping through rows, then finding elements within each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no `FindElementsByCssSelector` method in the selenium [IWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/IWebDriver.cs) interface.

But there is a [FindElements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/ISearchContext.cs) method that accepts [By](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/By.cs) queries:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody.items tr"));
```

---

There actually exists a method with such name and signature, but it is in the [IFindsByCssSelector](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver/Internal/IFindsByCssSelector.cs) interface, that is not implemented by the [IWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/IWebDriver.cs).

Comment: What does `.FindElementsByClassName` normally return then on a driver object? Maybe I shouldn't be looping `IWebElement`s. Also, please note that I'm not taking the call on the driver object. I'm making it on an element object.

Comment: @User Your first call seems to be on IWebDriver - `driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("tbody.items tr")`. And in any case just use `FindElements(By.CssSelector("...")`with either driver or element - that should work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

They must have removed this method between versions 3 and 4.  If you do not want to refactor your code using the API calls mentioned by @eugene-podskal, it would be easy enough to write some extension methods to add backward compatibility with your code (with optional pre-compiler symbol):

```
#if WEBDRIVER4

    /// <summary>
    /// Support for dropped methods
    /// </summary>
    public static class WebDriverExtensions
    {
        public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByCssSelector(this IWebDriver driver, string selector)
        {
            return driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(selector));
        }

        public static IWebElement FindElementByCssSelector(this IWebDriver driver, string selector)
        {
            return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
        }
    }

#endif
```